# Can my child live with me in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, children

So I am a British citizen, born and bred in the UK. My daughter (1 month old) lives in the USA also born there. I know she is a British citizen by decent.

My issue here is that my ex-partner (who is in the USA) wants me to look after our child and have my child living here with me in the United Kingdom as I can support her and she cant (So only my child coming).

Any ideas where I go with this? She shouldn't need a visa as she is British by decent anyway. I'm in a tricky situation because I have no idea where to go or if I can even just go and get my daughter like her mother wants me to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is get your child her British passport. Then you should be able to travel with her back to the United Kingdom, no problem. I've heard people say that you might need a letter from the other parent stating that she consents to you traveling alone with the child. I have done this trip both ways traveling alone with a daughter and had no problems whatsoever, but that was 7-8 years ago and things may have tightened up since then, so maybe it would not be a bad idea if the mother prepared a notarized authorization just in case. Other than that, it is very straightforward.

I'm assuming you are listed on the birth certificate as the father. If not, things get more complex if you are not married, which I've also assumed.

Comment: While a British passport is the best way to go, it should be noted that the child could also fly to the UK with a US passport (for the airline) and proof of British citizenship (for the immigration officer). In this case that would be the father's British passport, because it reflects birth in the UK, and the birth certificate or other proof of the father/daughter relationship.  This option could be useful if the parents want to get the child to the UK before the UK passport can be issued.

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies, this helps me greatly. We are not married, however i am on the birth certificate. Also the mother is willing to write a letter of agreement that i can have my daughter in my care now.